# Return self referencing nodes as a parent-child using neo4J OGM and cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-ogm

In the Neo4J database, I have an entity 'Person' which can be related to other Persons as a PARENT_OF or a CHILD_OF relationship

For instance, the cypher query

```
Match (p:Person) - [:PARENT_OF] -> (c:Person) where id(p) = {p_id} return p, c
```

will return a parent record p with id *p_id* and a set of child records c

In Java, I have a base class Person

```
public class Person {
    @GraphId private Long id;
    @Property @NonNull private String profile;
    @Relationship(type="RELATED_TO", direction="OUTGOING") Experience experience;
    @Relationship(type="RELATED_TO", direction="OUTGOING") Activity activity;
}
```

and 2 child classes

```
@NodeEntity (label="Person")
public class Parent extends Person {
    @Relationship(type="PARENT_OF", direction="OUTGOING") private List<Child> child;
}

@NodeEntity (label="Person")
public class Parent extends Person {
    @Relationship(type="PARENT_OF", direction="OUTGOING") private List<Child> children;
}
```

Assume suitable getters and setters

I want to use Neo4J-OGM in Java and get a Parent given a parent's id. This parent should have a list of Children pre-loaded

So a query case like this:

```
    final Iterable<Parent> parents = session.query(Parent.class, "MATCH (parent:Person) - [:PARENT_OF] -> (child:Person) where id(parent) = {personId} return parent --> child", ImmutableMap.of("personId", 15L));
    System.out.println (parent.get(0));
```

I want the parent object to be loaded with all its children (the List attribute should be populated).

How do I go about doing this? I need to use Cypher.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing to do is

`Person parent = session.load(Person.class, parentId);`
The default loading depth is one so it will load children. You can customize this depth if you wish.

Not sure why you need to use Cypher but if you want to, then the `loadAll` methods on the `Session` which accept `Filter` should work.

Here's an example https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/ogm/domain/tree/Entity.java

used in test https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/ogm/integration/tree/TreeIntegrationTest.java

Comment: Thanks @Luanne

Why do I need to use cypher? Because my code does not know that it is running a special "fetch by id" query. Queries are configured and run based on the situation

Now - load with a depth will load all relationships of a parent upto a particular depth. In this case, I am only interested in the "child" relationships of the parent - not its associations to "Activity" and other types.

Comment: Okay, then in that case, there is not enough support to handle what you're asking. Different depths per relationship, or mapping paths back into entities. Both are on the roadmap. Now your option is to use the above or to manually parse results back into your entities.

Comment: @Luanne Both link broken can you please update the Links.